# How can I draw only the largest rectangle contour to detect Vehicle License Plate (specifically for motorbike license plate)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, contour

I've been working on detecting motorbike license plate using only OpenCV. My question is:

1. Can I find and draw only the largest contour (which is around the license plate)?
2. If not then what should I do for this problem?
3. Are there any other methods for detecting motorbike license plate?

[image: Here is my original image]

[image: And here is the image after I detect every rectangle contours]

Here is the source code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('image_0002.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 120, 255, 1)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate thorugh contours and draw rectangles around contours
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imwrite('canny.png', canny)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Try thresholding and morphology to clean up small ones. Then get the external contours from findContours rather than using GaussianBlur and Canny

Comment: @fmw42 i will try to remove the small ones, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- For the largest rectangle  - calculate areas of all rectangles

```
largest_area = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = 4*w*h
    if area > largest_area:
        largest_area = area
        largest_area_contour = c
```

Now, we have got the largest rectangle. Lets draw it (outside of `for loop`).

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(largest_area_contour)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
```

2- Your model is giving you too many false positives. Ensure that largest rectangle method is always working.

3- License plate (car or bike doesn't matter) reading is a well studied toy problem. You will find many discussion on internet.

- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/09/21/opencv-automatic-license-number-plate-recognition-anpr-with-python/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-and-recognize-car-license-plate-from-a-video-in-real-time/

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for such detailed answers.

Comment: also, i just try with another 10 models and yes the largest rectangle method is not always working, so I think I will also try another methods. Thank you again

Comment: The width and height of the bounding rectangles is not the proper area when the rectangles are rotated. You should use cv2.contourArea()

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 ... yeah contourArea() is better as it covers all types of shapes.

Comment: The rectangles here are not rotated, so it won't matter though.